# Is it possible to specify the type of a Capability that has been stored as a generic Capability?

Tags: smartcontracts, onflow-cadence

I'm trying to store a dictionary of generic Capabilities inside a resource, something like

`pub let storedCapabilities: {String: Capability}`

But when I attempt to perform any action on one of those capabilities I got a "cannot infer type parameter: `T`", e.g.:

`self.storedCapabilities[tag]!.check()`

I have been trying to specify the capability type using [run-time types](https://developers.flow.com/cadence/language/run-time-types) functions such as:

```
fun CapabilityType(_ type: Type): Type?
fun ReferenceType(authorized: bool, type: Type): Type
```

But so far I haven't found the way.

Anybody knows if there's a proper of specifying a generic capability's type?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The Capability method `check` needs a type `T` in it in order to be used, otherwise it doesn't know what type it is checking for. Two options:

1. Use `cap.check<T>()`
2. Cast the capability into something with a type, then use check as you would normally

```
let cap = self.storedCapabilities[tag]!
let casted = cap as! Capability<T>
assert(casted.check(), message: "capability failed check")
```